# In Dart I'm trying to extend a class while changing the TYPE of one of its properties

Tags: class, flutter, dart, extends

Class1 has a property `List<ClassA> xyz = [];`.  ClassA has a number of properties and methods.  ClassB extends ClassA adding additional properties and methods.  Is there a way for me to create Class2 extending Class1 but change the TYPE of xyz to `List<ClassB>`?  If that is confusing hopefully code below  will give an example of what I'm trying to accomplish. Basically the same as overriding a method but overriding a property.

```
class Game {
  int points;
  String opponent;
  int opponentPoints;
}

class FootballGame extends Game {
  int touchdowns;
  int opponentstouchdowns;
}

class BaseballGame extends Game {
  int homeruns;
  int opponentsHomeruns;
}

class Team {
   String name;
   List<Game> games;

  double winningPercentage() {
    int wins = 0;
    for(var game in games){
      wins += (game.points > game.opponentPoints) ? 1 : 0;        
    }
    return wins / games.length;
  }
}

class FootballTeam extends Team {
  // How do I change the TYPE of the games property to <FootballGame>

}
```

Answer (score 7):

You could use the [`covariant` keyword](https://dart.dev/guides/language/sound-problems#the-covariant-keyword) in this case:

```dart
class FootballTeam extends Team {
  @override
  covariant List<FootballGame> games;
}
```

However, be aware that doing so is potentially unsafe; the reason why you need the `covariant` keyword is to suppress the type error that arises because the override can violate the contract of the base class: the base class advertises that `games` can be assigned a `List<Game>`, but such an assignment would be invalid for the derived class.  By using the `covariant` keyword, you disable the type-check and take responsibility for ensuring that you do not violate the contract in practice.

Note that if the `games` member were `final` (or were only a getter), then the override (which uses a more specific type) would be safe and wouldn't need to use `covariant`.

### Edit

I had forgotten that I had written this answer when writing [a more detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68971262/) for a similar question.