# "'Class.field=' isn't a valid override" when overriding a field with a more specific type

Tags: flutter, dart

```
abstract class Ainterface {
  String? name;
  List<Binterface?>? list;
}

abstract class Binterface {
  String? age;
  int? len;
}

class ObjA extends Ainterface {
  String? name;
  List<ObjB?>? list;
  ObjA({this.name, this.list});
}

class ObjB extends Binterface {
  String? age;
  int? len;
  ObjB({this.age, this.len});
}
```

I used objb as the type of each item in the list, but the editor gave an error 'obja. List =' ('void function (list < objb? >?)) isn't a valid override of 'Ainterface.list=' ('void Function(List<Binterface?>?)').

How I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fields (data members) in Dart implicitly provide getters and setters as part of the interface.  Therefore when you write:

```dart
abstract class Ainterface {
  List<Binterface?>? list;
}
```

The interface is implicitly:

```dart
abstract class Ainterface {
  List<Binterface?>? get list;
  set list(List<Binterface?>? value);
}
```

The problem is that your derived class wants to provide an interface:

```dart
class ObjA extends Ainterface {
  List<ObjB?>? get list;
  set list(List<ObjB?>? value);
}
```

Even though `List<ObjB?>?` is substitutable for `List<Binterface?>?`, the reverse is not true: `List<Binterface?>?` is *not* substitutable for `List<ObjB?>?`, and that's the direction that matters for the *setter*.

The `list` setter in `ObjA` *is not a safe override* of the corresponding setter from `Ainterface` because it would allow callers to violate its contract. `Ainterface.list` advertises that it allows being set to *any* instance of a `Binterface`, but `ObjA.list` expects *only* an instance of `ObjB`.  As a concrete example, if the override were allowed, then the following code would compile without error:

```dart
class AnotherB extends Binterface {}

void main() {
  Ainterface a = ObjA();
  a.list = [AnotherB()]; // This error would not be caught at compile-time.
}
```

And now `a.list` contains a `List<AnotherB>` even though `ObjA.list` expects `List<ObjB>`, and you'd eventually get an error at runtime if you try to use `a.list` as a `List<ObjB>`.

*If* you can logically guarantee that the above scenario will never happen, then you can use the `covariant` keyword to relax static type-checking and allow the override:

```dart
abstract class Ainterface {
  covariant List<Binterface?>? list;
}
```

but I re-emphasize that the above code removes some type-safety.  By using the `covariant` keyword, you take responsibility for ensuring that you do not violate the contract in practice.

Alternatively:

- Reconsider if your abstract base class needs to expose setters as part of its interface, and expose only getters if possible.
- Make `Ainterface` a generic class parameterized on the concrete type of `Binterface`:

  ```dart
  abstract class Ainterface<DerivedB extends Binterface> {
     List<DerivedB?>? list;
  }

  class ObjA extends Ainterface<ObjB> {
     List<ObjB?>? list;
  }
  ```

I'll also point out that [overriding fields is usually a bad idea](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/overridden_fields.html), and you usually should be explicitly overriding getters and setters anyway.

Answer (score 0):

In the `Ainterface` abstract class you declared that a list should be declared of type `Binterface` so any class extending that class should do that. so when you want to declare a class extending this class you should consider that.  if you want to also declare a list from type ObjB you can do it after that. it will be like this:

```
class ObjA extends Ainterface {
  String? name;
  List<Binterface?>? list;
  List<ObjB ?>? list2;
  ObjA({this.name, this.list, this.list2});
}
```